# find smallest sub segment

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have given a Long Sentence and some words(to be searched in the sentence),
i have to find the smallest part of the sentence which contains all the words to be Searched in that Sentence and print that part.

I have tried it,
1. First get all locations(indexes) of all words from the given sentence.
2. then try to find smallest part from these indexes of words.

But i am having problem implementing 2nd part .
So i want some advice for it or if you suggest any other algorithm which can make it fast.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ShotestSubSegment2 
{
static SearchStr[] search;
static String copystr;
public static void main(String s[])
{
try
{
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str = in.readLine();
        copystr = str.substring(0).toLowerCase();
        int k = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        search = new SearchStr[k];
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
            search[i] = new SearchStr(in.readLine().toLowerCase());
            getIndicesOf(search[i]);
            if(search[i].noOfElements()==0)
            {
                System.out.println("No Segments Found");
                return;
            }
        }
        searchSmallestPart();//Dont getting Idea Of this

    }
    catch(Exception x){}
}

public static void getIndicesOf(SearchStr searchS) 
{
    String searchStr = searchS.getName();
    int startIndex = 0, searchStrLen=0;
    int index;
    searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();
    searchStrLen = searchStr.length();
    while ((index = copystr.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) 
    {
        searchS.add(index);
        startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: please paste your code and an example as well

Comment: What have you tried?  If this is homework, mark this with the [homework] tag.

Comment: I have a feeling it is [homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224034/finding-sub-strings-of-string-containing-all-the-words-in-array)

Comment: Is the sequence in which the words appear also important? Can the words in the sentence repeat?

Comment: @Pshemo It may also be a crowdsourced hw, where the appointed dev is the asker here.

Comment: Lets say your long string is `"b a X c b"` and words are `"a"` `"b"` and `"c"`. How would subset(s) look like? Can we use same word few times to generate subset?

Comment: Example:
If i have a String > "Hello, my name is undefined. but your name is not undefined."  
and i have to search word [is, undefined]
then the answer should be printed is:
is undefined   //which is taken from the sentence 1st and we can not print from second sentence as it is " is not undefined" because it is not shortest.

Answer (score 0):

Using this class :

```
class FoundToken  {
   int start;
   end start;
   String word;
   int endOfCompleteSequence;
}
```

1) Store in a list all your found token with the start index and end index

2) For each of those list items, take the first complete sequence built from the following tokens (in the list) and containing all the desired ones

3) Take the shortest of those sequences (base on `endOfCompleteSequence-start)`.

Answer (score 0):

Store for each word into a list the positions where the word appears.

word1 - list1 of positions where word1 is found
word2 - list2 of positions where word2 is found
...

You have to minimize(Pend-Pstart) where Pstart is smallest position from the list of positions of a combination of valid positions for all words and Pend is the biggest one. To generate a combination for all words which where found in the text use backtracking.

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my algorithm. A bit laymen maybe, but that's the most basic approach that I figured out.

1. After input,loop throw the words and check which matches listed words.Proceed with an array which will store the listed words.
2. As soon as the match is found, mark that position and start another scan from that position and check for the match. Parallel remove the matched word from the list and check till all the words of the list are found. Till the next word is found , add all the words (in- the-between ones as well) in a string. this particular loop continues till all the elements of the listed words array is null.
3. Ones the innermost scan completes,Store the string ,hence found in another array(say String sol_array). and continue with the previous loop.(the previous loop runs for(original_string.length() - listed_word_array.length) times)
4. After the outermost loop completes, run a scan of the sol_array and check for the length of the string which is minimum, that string is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary variables:

- `bestseq` object/collection containing start/end of currently best sequence (initially e.g. `null`)
- `currently_closest` HashMap< word, index >  (replacing word and index by appropriate types, initially all special value e.g. -1)
- `current_start`, `current_end` (indices, initially e.g. -1)

"Algorithm":

1. run through the words in the string
2. if the current word is in words, store current index in currently_closest[word], adjust current_start and current_end to reflect the new maximum and minimum keys in currently_closest
3. if (`current_end-current_start<bestseq.end-bestseq.start` or `bestseq` is e.g `null`) and all words have non-special-indices (i.e. not -1) set => set bestseq to `current_start`,`current_end`-sequence

I guess this should run in O(length_of_sentence * number_of_words) time.